# Is there a way to vectorize a function that calculates a row dependable on previous rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, yahoo-finance

I am adding indicators to the stock market data, but my solution for finding the ATR is too slow. Is there a way to vectorize this problem?

I am using the yfinance library to get the stock prices.
At first I made a simple for loop, but then I realize it would take too long, and now I am using the Index to get previous row data. I tried using the .shift() function, but I need to get a slice of previous data because if I would use an average of 174, It would be hard to write.
For example I have this table: 

 
    Date        Open        High         Low       Close

 0 2017-10-23  156.839996  157.039993  155.949997  156.509995

 1 2017-10-23  156.529999  156.550095  155.929901  156.339996

 2 2017-10-23  156.320007  157.600006  156.119995  157.593994

 3 2017-10-23  157.599899  157.679993  157.279999  157.279999

 4 2017-10-23  157.297501  157.369995  156.559998  156.619995

And I would like to add an ATR column which is calculated by this formula:

Current ATR=(Prior ATR + Current TR)/2 in which 

Current TR = max[(high-low),(high - previous_close),(low-previous_close)]

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_prices(stock):
    ul = yf.Ticker(stock)
    pdate = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=729)).date()
    df = ul.history(start=pdate, interval="1H").drop(["Volume","Dividends", "Stock Splits"], axis=1)
    df = df.reset_index()
    return df

def addATR_(row, df, av=13):
    if(row.Index>av):
        lrid = row.Index-1
        high = row.High
        low = row.Low
        prev_close = df.loc[df.index==(lrid),"Close"]
        matr = df[row.Index-av:row.Index]["ATR"].sum()
        tr=[(high - low),np.abs(high - prev_close).values,np.abs(low - prev_close).values] 
        return (matr + np.max(tr))/(av+1)

def add_ATR(df):
    df.insert(5,"ATR", 0.2)
    df['Index'] = df.index
    df["ATR"] = df.apply(lambda row: addATR_(row, df), axis=1)
    df = df.drop(range(14))
    df = df.reset_index().drop(["index","Index"],axis=1)
    print("Added ATR")
    return df

print(add_ATR(get_prices("msft")))
```

I really want to speed things up, because it takes me 9 seconds to add only one Indicator.

Comment: Try to write so minimal code example that illustrates your problem. Provide your input data (a very small bunch) as literal in the code. Write what is a expected output. This will help other to understand the issue and solve it

Comment: Added a sample table and the ATR formula.

Comment: Can you provide expected outputs?

Comment: Line "prev_close = df.loc[df.index==(lrid),"Close"]" looks like source of the slowdown. It looks throught the whole data to find one with specific index. Try to precompute prev_close in a separate loop.